# make xcode play a sound when you have a compile error

Tags: xcode

I came across a Terminal one-liner for Xcode 3 that made it play the Inception "BWAAAAHNN" sound every time I tried to compile and hit an error. It worked great as a mistake deterrent, because nobody wants to be startled by that sound EVER.

Anybody know how this was done? Would it still work in Xcode 4?

Edit: thanks to Justin's hint  (Preferences > Behaviors > Build Fails > Play Sound) I worked out this:

```
curl http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/73/73581_634166-lq.mp3 -o /Developer/Extras/trombone.mp3
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode "Xcode.AlertEvents.4_1" -dict-add "Xcode.AlertEvent.BuildFails" '<dict><key>Xcode.Alert.Sound</key><dict><key>enabled</key><true/><key>soundPath</key><string>/Developer/Extras/trombone.mp3</string></dict></dict>'
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode "Xcode.AlertEvents" -dict-add "Xcode.AlertEvent.BuildFails" '<dict><key>Xcode.Alert.Sound</key><dict><key>enabled</key><true/><key>soundPath</key><string>/Developer/Extras/trombone.mp3</string></dict></dict>'
```

It's a little more than 1 line, though I'm  not sure if that third line is needed (Xcode seems to keep two versions of behaviour settings?).
Also, I picked a different sound this time. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Xcode 4, they are *Behaviors*.

Preferences > Behaviors > Build Fails > Play Sound

or Build Generates New issues

As far as irritating, a behavior can also speak to you, or open and close your project's views, and more, and you can *combine* them O_O.

Comment: =) You're the employee of the month, aren't you?    _ _ _ *man defaults* ;)

Comment: it took a fair bit more digging than that. Xcode has at least 3 .plist files in ~/Library/Preferences, and the key is deeply nested inside com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist. As the last line in *man defaults* mentions "**BUGS** `Defaults can be structured in very complex ways, making it difficult for the user to enter them with this command.`"